# QQuickPaintedItem and QwtPlotPicker: how to force them to work together

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qwt

There's a class inherited `QQuickPaintedItem` and included `QwtPlot` (in order to use it in QML):

```
class QmlQwtPlot : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QmlQwtPlot(QQuickItem* parent = 0);
    ~QmlQwtPlot();

    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override;

private:
    QwtPlot* qwtPlot;
    QwtPlotPanner* panner;
    bool isDragging;
    QPoint previousPosition;
    QwtPlotPicker* picker;
};
```

For example, panning a plot was implemented by using mouse events handling and the `QwtPlotPanner`'s signal :

```
void QmlQwtPlot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    if (isDragging) {  // if the mouse button has been pressed
        QPoint currentPosition = event->pos();
        QPoint diff = currentPosition - previousPosition;
        emit panner->panned(diff.x(),diff.y());
        previousPosition = event->pos();
        update();
    }
}
```

`QwtPlotPicker` is a [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) library class providing selections on a plot canvas. `QwtPlotPicker` works well (a cursor with x,y coordinates of point and cross-line moving with cursor are appeared) with `QWidget`, but it doesn't work with `QQuickPaintedItem` because of different principles of work.

```
/* QWidget's child constructor (the same is in QQuickPaintedItem's one) */
PlottingWidget::PlottingWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    // ...
    d_picker = new QwtPlotPicker(
        QwtPlot::xBottom, QwtPlot::yLeft,
        QwtPlotPicker::CrossRubberBand,
        QwtPicker::AlwaysOn,
        plot->canvas() 
    );

    d_picker->setRubberBandPen( QColor( Qt::red ) );
    d_picker->setTrackerPen( QColor( Qt::black ) );
    d_picker->setStateMachine( new QwtPickerTrackerMachine() );

    // ...
}
```

How to force `QwtPlotPicker` work with `QQuickPaintedItem`?

Comment: What is the problem? What does "work with"mean? What `QwtPlotPicker` is?

Comment: @folibis Updated the post for you.